# Why by default without constructor the variable or pointer values of the user defined class in cpp points to 0 or NULL?

Tags: c++

I have a very simple class node where I have two variables and one pointer int, string and pointer to same class when I am printing them without any initialization

The int shows zero, string empty string, and pointer point to NULL

My question is this, this is how it should be shouldn't they be pointing to some random value and is this compiler specific thing ?

Below is the code for the same

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
public:
    int x;
    string y;
    node* ptr;
};
int main()
{
    node* node1=new node;
    cout<<node1->x<<endl;
    cout<<node1->y<<endl;
    cout<<node1->ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Output the code gives in my compiler

```
0

0x0
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Both `x` and `ptr` are _uninitialized_. Whether they happen to contain zero or any other value is completely down to chance.

Comment: But Every time I run the code in my compiler I am receiving the same output, so is this specific to my compiler

Comment: Yes, that's the nature of **undefined behavior**.  It may appear to be consistent.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is often consistent until suddenly it isn't.

Comment: OS zeroes the memory before supplying it to an app for security. You should not expect it, you don't know if it's new memory or not.

Comment: @FSI So what? It's still undefined behavior. Your compiler _might_ zero-initialize memory in certain debug modes. Or it might not. Or the standard library might do it, or it might not. Or the memory might just happen to be "clean" or it might not. I don't really know what the goal here is. You are too lazy to write a constructor?

Comment: Note that zero is a perfectly valid example of "some random value".

Comment: @273K Can you please explain it more the OS zeros part not able to understand what you are saying

Comment: My favorite example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_aQLBVuZns How many times do you think that demo was run before Bill Gates, pretty much at the peak of his unholy power, was convinced to get up in front of an audience?

Comment: No No @paddy I am amazed why this was happening as It should not be this the case
But understood what you guys are saying thanks a lot

Comment: If your program can easily surf through old values in memory can you imagine all of the fun stuff you could learn? Passwords, decrypted secure files, URLs to visited adult sites...

Comment: @FSI Whether it operates how you expect to or not It's **undefined behavior** therefore your expectations are just as ill formed as the code. End of story.

Comment: Too many people come to the belief that the meaning of "undefined" is that some random value is produced, or that a program will crash in gruesome ways.  The reality is that "undefined" means "the standard doesn't constrain what happens".   Producing zero is just as reasonable an outcome (in some cases, more so) than producing random output.   If the standard was rewritten to replace all occurrences of "undefined" with requirements to electrocute the programmer (and if implementations complied) the number of programmers would be significantly smaller and the ones left would be more competent.

Comment: Or at least much more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't they be pointing to some random value and is this compiler specific thing ?

No. The value is uninitialized and therefore the contents of the memory is undefined. Whether it is consistently zero or some other value in your local tests is completely irrelevant.

If you want to value-initialize the new memory without a constructor, then add parentheses in the call to `new` as follows:

```
node* node1 = new node();
```

The above guarantees that each member of node will be value-initialized. For the `std::string` member, that will be the default constructor (which it always was anyway). But for the members `x` and `ptr` this now guarantees they are zero.

Alternatively, you can provide a default constructor to initialize your values:

```
class node{
public:
    int x;
    string y;
    node* ptr;

    node()
        : x()
        , ptr()
    { }
};
```

Or you can use member-initialization syntax (unsure of the exact term) as of C++11:

```
class node{
public:
    int x = 0;
    string y;
    node* ptr = nullptr;
};
```